# webpage group for user to join using node express and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Is there an example to create a webpage group for user to join the GROUP displayed in UI ? using node express and react

Comment: What do you mean by webpage group?

Comment: @MdJahidHasan009 basically I need to learn how to create an web app which display group and user will have an ability to join any group .thanks

Comment: you can try this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc

Comment: @MdJahidHasan009 its more for chat system , my requirement is different to that.
I need to be able to create mutliple groups and then user will be able to click join any group .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.